# Some devices on LAN suffer from slow Internet speeds

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have just installed a Draytek 2925n+ in our small office.

We have about 10 devices (PC and Macs) hard wired into a gigabit switch, which is connected to the router. I have factory reset the switch to make sure that is not interfering with anything.

So, there are 5 Windows machines, 3 of which can access the Internet without issue and good speed.

The other two are suffering from either slow connection to the Internet, or none at all.

I wired one of the slow machines directly into the router, and the problem persists. I noticed on this machine, that the wired network connection in Windows has the wrong name assigned to it, taking the name of the WiFi SSID, and not the name given to the LAN connection in the router settings.

No QoS is active on the router.

I also have two Macs (Mac Mini and an iMac) that refuse to receive a leased IP via DHCP on their ethernet adapters. The WiFi adapters on both work fine with picking up a leased IP.

I'm pulling my hair out here, as we got this router to replace a crapped out one (Billion BiPac 7800) but it's causing more havoc then that was!

Comment: Have you factory reset the 2925n when you received it (not the switch, as you mention)? I've used the 2920n's a few times and they're great. You might want to try resetting the network stacks on the problem machines. Also, delete any wireless profiles on the hard wired machines so they're not tempted to connect to wireless. Finally, reset the Windows Firewslls of the problem machines.

Comment: How do I reset the network stacks? I'm going to reset the router now. And how do I reset Win Firewall?

Comment: To reset Windows Firewall: `Control panel` -> `Windows Firewall` -> `Restore defaults` down the left. To reset IP stack: `cmd` (as Administrator) -> `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299357. I would also do `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /flushdns` and `ipconfig /renew` for good measure. I'd also check the Network and Sharing Center to see what speed the NICs are set to. Sometimes `Auto-negotiate` can be problematic...

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using dynIP change it to Static IP, and gives every PC a
  specific IP depend on their MAC address,
- second try to ping a PC from other device, see if there is a V-LAN on your
  router or not, and be sure all your devices on the same subnet mask
- Be sure there is no two DHCP service on your network, that's will cause a lot of problems

Comment: Regarding assigning static IPs, should this be done via the router or on the machines? The DrayTek lets you bind and IP to a MAC address, but then Windows will let you set one and get that IP form the router instead of an automatically assigned one. No VLAN present (as in, there has never been one setup) and There are no other routers and the switch is just set as standard, so no idea if that has DHCP on it, I dont think so

Comment: As you like :) from router or PC, it's the same, but what about your modem?! support DHCP or it's just a modem? last thing be sure what you have switch or not, check every machine is there any weird gateway!? or weird IP and what is your DNS?

Comment: We have a bonded line, and the modem just feeds the router.

Comment: If you've never had a problem between previous router and modem then modem is not the problem. If some machines work perfectly and others don't then problem is not between modem and Vigor 2925n+. If you have swapped out a router and the DHCP addresses are different then some of the machines need to have their leases expired via the OS...